# Exporting Highcharts SVG with HTML elements

Tags: highcharts

I am saving a a chart as SVG, using the getGSV() method. The chart in question is a rather complex pie chart, that uses formatters to annotate the slices with information. These labels however do not show up in the SVG export, it just contains the unannotated chart. I am aware that by default, exporting HTML in svg is not supported, so i tried enabling the allowHTML option, but my problem remains unsolved.

In the method that assembles the data structure:

```
"dataLabels": {
                style: {
                    width: '70px',
                    textAlign: 'right'
                },
                enabled: true,
                useHTML: true,  /*already defined in the chart options */
                formatter: function()
{console.log(i18next.t("component."+this.point.name+".name")); return
i18next.t("component."+this.point.name+".name") + "<br>" + results[this.point.name]["pie_score"] + "%"},
                "distance": -50,
            },
```

and at another point, in the chart definition:

```
exporting: {
                allowHTML: true,
                enabled: false
            },
```

The SVG is simply exported via chart.getSVG()...

To clarify, i am merely adding an export pipelin to existing code, so i know the charts themselves work and look as intended, they are only screwed up in the export.

Comment: Could you please post live example of your issue? Like jsFiddle?